# Need answer for this from R language with some explanation

Tags: r

1. Suppose age is a vector containing ages of 10 persons as
   22,27,31,41,30,25,19,20,23,35.

**Create a vector ‘age30’ with age of person > 30?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can subset the original vector based on the logical condition

```
age30 <- ages[ages > 30]
```